# IIS URL Redirect Applying to All Site when it shouldn't

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, global

I am trying to do some simple URL rewrites in IIS for Jira. I can make the rewrite work for one site but it is applying the rules to all sites which mess up my configurations. I have recently reconfigured everything and before It was working how I expected it.

This is what I am doing:

Open IIS Manager > Expand Server > Expand Site > Select Specific Site > Click on Feature (URL Rewrite) > Add in rules config > Apply.

At this point this rule is in every site being applied, to include the default site. If I select a new site and click URL Rewrite the rule is there. I can also delete or disable the rule from any site and it apply that everywhere?

Does any one know if there is a setting some where I some switched or a bug? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your site's advanced settings (right click on the site > Manage Website > Advanced Settings)  and check the physical path of each site.  I think you may find that all your sites are pointing to the same path and using the same Web.config file.  That would cause this behavior as changing one site would change the single web.config that all the sites are using.

To fix this problem you'd need a separate path for each site (and by extension a separate web.config file for each would automatically be created.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set rewrite rules on the serve level and on the site level.

The behavior you describe is correct when you have created a rule on the server level, but you clearly state that you selected a single site only.

If changing a rule on a site level indeed changes the rules on the server level, that would indeed be a bug, but I don't fully believe you on this.

Double check that you are editing rules on the site node, not the server node.

Site rules are usually stored in the web.config file of the site, server rules are stored in a node `<rewrite><globalRules> in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

check these locations and see how they change after you made changes in the GUI.